# Search abbreviations and acronyms on Azure Cognitive Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Does anyone provide the way to Search abbreviations and acronyms on Azure Cognitive Search? For example, if user search the word: "PWC". "Price Waterhouse Coopers" will also be on the search results besides "PWC" results.

I have tried to use: abbreviations:"PWC" on the index of Azure Cognitive Search, however, "Price Waterhouse Coopers" are not on the search results.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution for this is to use a `synonym map`.

I have created a synonym map and index with below code snippet:

```py
import requests
import json

search_service_name = "your_search_service_name"
api_key = "your_api_key"
api_version = "2020-06-30"

headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "api-key": api_key
}

# Create a synonym map
synonym_map_url = f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/synonymmaps?api-version={api_version}"
synonym_map_data = {
    "name": "my-synonym-map",
    "format": "solr",
    "synonyms": "PWC, Price Waterhouse Coopers"
}

response = requests.post(synonym_map_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(synonym_map_data))

index_url = f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes?api-version={api_version}"
index_data = {
    "name": "my-index",
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "id",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "key": True,
            "filterable": True,
            "sortable": True,
            "facetable": True
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "Edm.String",
            "searchable": True,
            "filterable": True,
            "sortable": True,
            "facetable": True,
            "synonymMaps": ["my-synonym-map"]
        }
    ]
}

response = requests.post(index_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(index_data))

document_url = f"https://{search_service_name}.search.windows.net/indexes/my-index/docs/index?api-version={api_version}"
document_data = {
    "value": [
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "id": "1",
            "name": "Price Waterhouse Coopers"
        }
    ]
}
response = requests.post(document_url, headers=headers, data=json.dumps(document_data))
```

When you create a `synonym map`, you can specify that the full form of an abbreviation should be returned when you search for the abbreviation.

As shown below, the required search term is in the result with abbreviation search query.

[image]

For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/create-synonym-map).

Comment: Thank you for your details answer. Future more question, it is we have to define synonym map by ourselves. There are very long list of abbreviations and acronyms. I am wondering whether Cognitive Search or other Azure services have the capability to identify the abbreviation itself automatically like Bing Search? Thank you.